# Content Length in $_FILE

Tags: php

I'm not a PHP expert at all so please forgive me if I make incorrect or stupid statements!  I recently had my web server uprgaded to PHP 7.4.11 from PHP 5.  In addition to running Joomla that server also contains a PHP script that receives a file via POST and moves it to a specified folder.  This is sent form a .NET client that crucially does not put the Content-Length header into the post with the content type of ' multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------8d8cf4b4721703d\n'.

The file is notified as being correctly received by this PHP code:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
```

On PHP5 this was working just fine, on PHP7 it is not.  When testing with Postman, we determined that if the Content-Length header is present the $_FILES['file'] contains the file but if Content-Length is not present it will not contain the file.  The call typically comes as a post from a .NET application that we have determined does not send the Content-Length header

How can I get PHP7 to replicate the behaviour of PHP5; note that I cannot change the sender as it is a .NET rich client application installed and I can't get to the client to change it.

Thanks for your help.

Cheers,

Neil

Comment: Can you show a var_dump of $_FILES['file']?

Comment: NULL without content_length

Comment: array(5) {
["name"]=>
string(16) "dp5-headless.xml"
["type"]=>
string(15) "application/xml"
["tmp_name"]=>
string(14) "/tmp/phpcds2Nr"
["error"]=>
int(0)
["size"]=>
int(989)
}

with content_length

Comment: Update, I tried turning enable_post_data_reading to off and reading php://input.  Again if content-length is set it works but if content-length is not set it will not work.

Comment: Rather surprising it works even with a content-length set, since the manual says, _“php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".”_

Comment: I set enable_post_data_reading to off in php.ini so that php://input is available.  Not a permanent solution but if worked I could have used apache trickery to set a php_value when calling this specific script.